# Copy missing shared libraries (.so files) to target host

Tags: python, c++, gcc, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

CentOS: 
`pip install opencv-python`
This module fails at runtime.
`ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Ubuntu: The module works fine on Ubuntu.

As I understand:

- On Ubuntu, use `gcc` to create an archive containing libGL.so.1
- Copy the archive, setup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly in CentOS

Query: How to copy missing SO from Ubuntu to CentOS and make it available for any program that tries to use it.

I saw multiple articles on internet, but the starting point for all of them is .c file. However, in this case, the starting point is a python module and we don't have a .c file to start with.

`opencv-python-headless` / `libGL` are just for example.

Comment: No, CentOS should have its own packages containing libGL, it depends on which graphics card you have.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I am using docker CentOS (docker pull centos). I am able to replicate the error. Moreso, I am interested to know the process how to copy SOs from source to target - openCV/libGL are just for example. Thanks.

(venv-x) [root@c842b4701dc4 cv2]# ldd cv2.abi3.so | grep "not found"
        libGL.so.1 => not found
        libGL.so.1 => not found

Comment: libGL is a system library, so it does not work as an example.

Comment: hmm, okay. Trash opencv/libGL. On a generic sense, how do we transfer SOs to target host and make them available for any program that intends to use it?